# How do I test whether a string would match a glob in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, glob

Without hitting the filesystem, is it possible to see whether the glob `"foo*"` would match `"food"` in Ruby?

**Background**: one of my scripts produce files, and I'd like to unit test that other scripts would be able to detect such files with their current glob.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using the [`fnmatch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000001) method:

```
File.fnmatch("foo*", "food") #=> true
```