# Check if string matches glob patern

Tags: ruby, glob

Is there a way to check and see if a string matches a [`Dir.glob` pattern](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob)?

Eg if `'/foo/bar/baz.jpg'` matches `'*.{jpg,png}'`

Comment: Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186361/how-do-i-test-whether-a-string-would-match-a-glob-in-ruby

Comment: Or, just go directly to the docs for [File.fnmatch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/File.html#method-c-fnmatch) for a more detailed description and lots of examples.